# BLU Win HD and 4G LTE with T-mobile

Tags: blu-win-hd

I want to buy BLU Win HD and use it with T-mobile.

But in this [review](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2458334,00.asp), it's written:

> The Win HD supports GSM (850/900/1800/1900MHz) and HSDPA+ 42
>   (850/1900/1700MHz), but unfortunately doesn't work with 4G LTE.

On [T-mobile site](http://www.t-mobile.com/cell-phone-plans/individual.html):

> PLUS use your monthly 4G LTE data in Mexico and Canada like in the
>   U.S., at no extra charge.

What does it mean? Will phone work in Canada?